# Suppose I have a long-format data-frame df, and clean it with na.omit, then perform correlation in it via cor

Tags: r

Suppose I have a long-format data-frame df, and clean it with na.omit, then perform correlation in it via `cor` (i.e. `cor(na.omit(df))`). What is the equivalent code in R?

```r
Cor (df, use=”p”)
Cor(df, use=”complete.obs”)
Cor (df, na.omit=TRUE)
Cor (df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Isn't this already R code?

Comment: Yes, it's r code. I'm just trying to figure out what code is equivalent to cor(na.omit(df))). I'm thinking it's Cor(df, use="complete.obs")

Comment: If I understand you correctly, would you want to use `cor(df[complete.cases(df),])`? This is a confusing question so not sure if this is what you are looking for.